# Cannot download .Net Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For some reason I cannot download the .Net Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack. Here's the link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

I select English langage, click Download, and I'm redirected to a Thankyou for your download. But nothing happens.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I don't think this site is the one to help you with this issue.

Comment: this is is not a site for these type of issues, but check if the popup in the browser is not blocked.

Comment: What happens when you click the "If your download does not start after 30 seconds, Click here" link on the thank you page?

Comment: @RaviShankar: I do not have popups blocked.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I don't see that text on the thankyou page.

Comment: @brinch https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4m3P.png

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: This is what I see: https://ibb.co/kTDnL5

Comment: Don't see why this should be downvoted. The answer might come in handy for other people, who don't see the download link either.

Comment: @brinch - It's downvoted because this question has nothing to do with programming, and is more suitable for a site like SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it does not work for you and why the "If your download does not start after 30 seconds, Click here" does not show up for you, but here is a direct link to where the "click here" link takes you to on my machine

https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/F/D/EFD52638-B804-4865-BB57-47F4B9C80269/NDP462-DevPack-KB3151934-ENU.exe

Comment: That works for me - thanks :-)